# Yahoo Email listner to fetch mail from yahoo mail account in java

Tags: java, yahoo, pop3, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I wanna know how to fetch new email which just came in my yahoo mail inbox using java code.

Instead of using a time-interval based job I want that whenever a new mail arrives in my yahoo mail inbox, then only it should trigger my server.

Something like a web socket connection as like the back-end server automatically pushes the notification on client side whenever there is a change on server side.

Like wise **I want yahoo mail to trigger my server API whenever there is a new email.**

I digged up the internet for solution but **could only find the solution for gmail but not yahoo**. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Third party API are also welcome.

Comment: Unless you find Yahoo documentation saying otherwise, it may not exist.  Their IMAP solution does not support IDLE (the IMAP push solution), and any HTTP solution would be custom to Yahoo.

Comment: OK Thanks for the update.